# How to implement function like f(k+1) = f(k)**2 + 3 * a(k)

Tags: python-3.x, function

How can I implement a function like

```
f(k+1) = f(k)**2 + 3 * a(k)
```

with

```
a(k) = 1 + sin(2*k/1000)
f(1) = 10
```

when i want to implement functions like f(k+1) ?

Comment: ..in what programming language?

Comment: Sorry, in python.  
Python doesent like the "k+1"
as an function argument

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having trouble with? Is it that you don't know how to do exponentiation? Is it that you don't know how to write a function that is based on itself?

Comment: First step would be to rewrite the definition so that it starts with `f(k) = ...` instead of `f(k+1)`. Then let us know where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming question. But it is solvable with iteration (assuming integers)

Comment: Im new to Python, but i want to implement RL-control and the functions are given.

So i cant write the f(k+1) in to f(k) because then i also have to rewrite the a(k) to a(k-1)

But still don`t know how the exponentiation of function in python works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming k+1 is a positive integer > 1, you can solve it with iteration like so. For all integers you will have to modify it further, for non-integers you'd do better to ask in math.stackexchange.com how to convert to a generalized form.

Edit: This is C psuedo-code, originally OP had no programming language listed with his question.

```
-(int)f:(int)kp1 {
    if (kp1-1 == 1) {
        return 10;
    } else {
        return pow([self f:kp1-1],2) + 3 * [self a:kp1-1];
    }
}
-(int)a:(int)k {
    return 1+sin(2*k/1000.0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly i didn`t get it...

How would you solve it in Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want is a recursive function, for further reading on this type of thing lookup a recursive factorial function in python. As far as this problem is concerned I think something like this would do it:

```py
import math

def a(k):
    return 1 + math.sin(2*k/1000.0)

def f(k):
    if k == 1:
        return 10
    else:
        return f(k-1)**2 + 3*a(k-1)
```

Note: this is basically just a python implementation of Albert Renshaw psuedo-code answer so some credit is due there

Comment: Thanks! 
i will try that!